# How to login without Microsoft account after update

Tags: windows-10, login

My computer did an update overnight and now I can't login because it is forcing me to provide my Microsoft account creds and I don't remember the password. Of course I am going to reset my password and get in, but in the past there was always an option to login w/o having to use a Microsoft account which is what I prefer.

Is this option still available somehow, or has Microsoft now locked it down so that you absolutely must use your Microsoft account?

Comment: “Is this option still available somehow, or has Microsoft now locked it down so that you absolutely must use your Microsoft account?” - If your account wasn’t linked to a Microsoft account before the update, it shouldn’t have been linked to an account after the account without taking specific actions, it is indeed possible to create an account without it being linked to a Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch from a Microsoft Account to a Local Account:

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-switch-local-account-microsoft-account-windows-10

> How to switch to local account using Settings To switch to a local
> account from a Microsoft account on Windows 10, use these steps:
>
> Open Settings. Click on Accounts. Click on Your info. Click the Sign
> in with a local account instead option.

Or, you can make another Local Account to use.

You can use whichever option is best for you.

You are not obligated to use a Microsoft Account if you do not wish to.

Comment: How exactly is the author going to do that, if they are unable to log into their account, in order to access the Settings application?

Comment: If this was an initial install it would still be annoying, but not infuriating. The fact that they change the login type on an update is absolutely terrible.

Comment: I doubt they did. I believe OP has a MS account and was using Hello to use a PIN or alternate Auth method. The update is far more likely to have messed with a Hello function than it is to have converted a local account to an MS account.